# JAR file won't run BUT it doesn't produce an error

Tags: java, jar

Until a day ago I ran jar files (jdownloader) fine and suddenly it couldn't but it was trying to find an app to run it. I changed it to use the jre environment, but then it would do like it was trying to open and then nothing. I uninstalled the jre and installed it again but the same. It doesn't produce an error or anything but it just loads for a while (the mouse changing to the loading animation) and then nothing, like it ran but the end result was just nothing

Running java -jar path_to_jar

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it/sauronsoftware/junique/AlreadyLockedException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.sauronsoftware.junique.AlreadyLockedException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
```

Comment: open a command prompt, and execute the command `java -jar yourJarFile.jar`. Post the result.

Comment: Now you know what the problem is. The class `it.sauronsoftware.junique.AlreadyLockedException` is missing in the jar file, or a jar dependency is missing in the classpath entry of the jar's manifest.

Comment: doesn't really say anything to me, especially since this is the same file that yesterday was running fine...

Comment: Are you a developer familiar with Java and who develops the application that you're trying to use, or are you a simple end user. It the former, it should say something to you. If the latter, then report the bug to the person or company that gave/sold you this program.